# Is $\{I_{a,b}\mid -\infty \leq a\leq b\leq \infty \}$ $\pi-$system where $I_{a,b}\in \{(a,b),(a,b],[a,b),[a,b]\}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Is $$\mathcal P=\{\infty \}\cup\{I_{a,b}\mid -\infty <a\leq b<\infty \}$$ $\pi-$system where $I_{a,b}\in \{(a,b),(a,b],[a,b),[a,b]\}$ ? I think they are (it anyway looks like), but I don't understand why we always consider $\{(a,b]\mid a<b\}$ not not really the other cases. For instance, if $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space and $X$ is a random variable, I always see : let consider the unique probability $\mathbb Q$ s.t. $\mathbb Q((a,b])=\mathbb P\{X\in (a,b]\}$. But instead of taking $(a,b]$, we could define $\mathbb Q$ using $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ ? Or also $(-\infty ,a]$, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution functions defined by $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$ are not cotninuous in general. But they are right continuous. On the other hand $P(X< x)$ is left continuous. It is customary to use the right continuous version to construct $\mathbb Q$ (in which case we get $\mathbb Q ((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$) but we can also use left continuous functions $G$ defined by $G(x)=P(X<x)$. In this case $\mathbb Q ([a,b))=G(b)-G(a)$ and we can use this to construct the measure $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for each of those four cases the family $\mathcal P$ is a $\pi$-system. With that being said, oftentimes the point of using a $\pi$-system is to work with as small a collection as possible (compared to the whole $\sigma$-algebra) so that whatever property you are trying to prove needs to be checked in the simplest cases only.

Anyway, to properly answer the question would require knowing exactly which context the $\pi$-system is being used in. Most textbooks I have seen take care to use a minimal $\pi$-system that will accomplish the job...